# Iterate through Nested Object's properties to flatten in an array using ES5 or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I have a `keys` property that is related to `map` property. The length of `keys` correspond with how deep the level of each map property goes. In this case only 2 levels.
If I add another entry to `keys` then each map property will go one more level deeper.

Below is the data

```
    {
     keys: [
      "vendorApNbr",
      "type"
     ],
     map: {
       _default: {              <-** 1st level
         _default: "'100026'",   <-** 2nd level
         PT_CC: "'120035'",      <-** 2nd level
         PT_DC: "'120037'"
       },
       A-00: {                <- ** 1st level
         _default: "'120037'"    <- ** 2nd level
       },  
       A-01: {
         _default: "'120035'"
       },
       A-02: {
         _default: "'120035'"
       },
       A-03: {
         _default: "'120036'"
       }, 
       A-04: {
         _default: "'100024'"
       }
     }
    }
```

I would like to create an array of arrays where each item in the array is iteration of going from level 1 to level 2 (but can go down more levels if needed)

i.e.

```
    [
      ['_default', '_default', "'10026'"],
      ['_default', 'PT_CC', "'120035'"],
      ['_default', 'PP_DC', "'120037'"],
      ['A-00', '_default', "'120037'"],
      ['A-01', '_default', "'120035'"],
      ...etc
      ['A-04', '_default', "'100024'"]
    ]
```

I'm limited to ES5 or lodash. I'm thinking of recursion but not sure how to approach this. Any suggestion can help.

**Edit**
also to have a way to turn the array form back to nested object form

Answer (score 1):

What about this? It doesn't care about how many nested the object is and what the level is. Additionally, each depth could be different.

```js
var obj = {
    "_default": {
        "_default": "'100026'",
        "PT_CC": "'120035'",
        "PT_DC": "'120037'"
    },
    "A-00": {
        "_default": "'120037'"
    },  
    "A-01": {
        "_default": "'120035'"
    },
    "A-02": {
        "_default": "'120035'"
    },
    "A-03": {
        "_default": "'120036'"
    }, 
    "A-04": {
        "_default": "'100024'"
    }
}

var result = [];

function rec(acc, obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "object") {
        for (var key in obj) {
            rec(acc.concat([key]), obj[key]);
        }

        return;
    }

    result.push(acc.concat([obj]));
}

rec([], obj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sounds great. I’ll try this out. Also looking for a way to go from array form back to nested object form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [Depth-Fist Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#:%7E:text=Depth%2Dfirst%20search%20(DFS),along%20each%20branch%20before%20backtracking.).

The code below is an example extracted from [this webpage](https://www.collegestash.com/use-dfs-flatten-javascript-object/). The difference here is that is concatenates every key, but you can use the same algorithm with some modifications to get a list.

```js
 var obj = {
  baz: {
    foo: {
      bar: "5"
    },
    hell: {
      sin: "0"
    }
  },
  a: {
    b: "1"
  }
};
 
var hash = {};
var str = '';
 
var dfs = function(obj, str) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'string')
        hash[str + key] = obj[key];
      else {
        dfs(obj[key], str + key + '.');
      }
    }
  }
};
dfs(obj, str);
console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **recursive function** to flatten the object's properties in an array.

This function...

- only takes **one parameter** as argument and
- doesn't rely on external vars

```js
var data = {
  keys: [
    "vendorApNbr",
    "type"
  ],
  map: {
    _default: {
      _default: "'100026'",
      PT_CC: "'120035'",
      PT_DC: "'120037'"
    },
    A00: {
      _default: "'120037'"
    },
    A01: {
      _default: "'120035'"
    },
    A02: {
      _default: "'120035'"
    },
    A03: {
      _default: "'120036'"
    },
    A04: {
      _default: "'100024'"
    }
  }
};

function makeItFlat(data) {
  var newArray = [];
  var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data);

  for (var prop of properties) {
    if (typeof data[prop] === 'object') {
      var flat = makeItFlat(data[prop]);

      for (var f of flat) {
        if (!Array.isArray(f)) {
          f = [f];
        }
        newArray.push([prop].concat(f));
      }
    } else {
      newArray.push([prop].concat([data[prop]]));
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

var flatArray = makeItFlat(data.map);
console.log(flatArray);
```

For converting the array back to the original object, you can use this code:

```js
var flatArray = [
  ["_default", "_default", "'100026'"],
  ["_default", "PT_CC", "'120035'"],
  ["_default", "PT_DC", "'120037'"],
  ["A00", "_default", "'120037'"],
  ["A01", "_default", "'120035'"],
  ["A02", "_default", "'120035'"],
  ["A03", "_default", "'120036'"],
  ["A04", "_default", "'100024'"]
];

function convertArrayOfStringsToObject(flatArray) {
  var newObject = {};
  var key = flatArray[0];
  var entry = null;

  if (flatArray.length == 2) {
    entry = flatArray[1];
  } else {
    entry = convertArrayOfStringsToObject(flatArray.slice(1));
  }

  if (key in newObject) {
    //key exists already, then merge:
    Object.assign(newObject[key], entry);
  } else {
    newObject[key] = entry;
  }
  return newObject;
}

function expandArray(flatArray) {
  var newObject = {}
  for (var line of flatArray) {
    var key = line[0];
    var entry = convertArrayOfStringsToObject(line.slice(1));
    if (key in newObject) {
      //key exists already, then merge:
      Object.assign(newObject[key], entry);
    } else {
      newObject[key] = entry;
    }
  }
  return newObject;
}

console.log(expandArray(flatArray));
```